# How to mock @react-native-community/geolocation with detox?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, detox

**Describe the Bug**

Detox test crashes when used with Geolocation module

**Error**

```
Error: @react-native-community/geolocation: NativeModule.RNCGeolocation is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
• Run `react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation` in the project root.
• Rebuild and re-run the app.
• If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation

<global>
    nativeInterface.js:17:8
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    implementation.native.js:11
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.js:11
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    TravelTimeContainer.js:3
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.js:1
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    MyDay.js:5
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    BottomTabNavigator.js:14
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    AppNavigator.js:16
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    Setup.js:8
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    App.js:2
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.js:6
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:201:45
global code
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:195242:4
```

**Environment (please complete the following information):**

- "react-native": "0.61.1",
- "react": "^16.9.0",
- "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
- "detox": "^14.4.1",

**Note**

- I'm running the tests on iOS simulator.
- The Geolocation library is linked correctly and works fine at runtime.

Please provide a solution to the same.

Comment: Please provide the test code that you are working with and having reproducible error.

Comment: You can just added the geolocation library with detox and no test would run.

Comment: What solution did you find?

Answer (score 3):

There was a solution that worked for me that was posted on github here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation/issues/44#issuecomment-512720306

Hey @SergejDK , you need to mock the `RNCGeolocation` native module. Create a folder `__mocks__` on the root level. Inside already created folder create another folder `@react-native-community` and within that folder create a file called `geolocation.js`, where you have to specify mocks:

```
export default {
  addListener: jest.fn(),
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn(),
  removeListeners: jest.fn(),
  requestAuthorization: jest.fn(),
  setConfiguration: jest.fn(),
  startObserving: jest.fn(),
  stopObserving: jest.fn()
};
```

Folders structure should look like:

```
.
├── __mocks__/
│   │── @react-native-community/ 
│       | -- geolocation.js
```